# Insert element between others in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm a novice with Bootstrap and I've this situation:
there are 3 blocks that I would like make them appear in this 2 way:
When I see the page with a large screen
[image: main view]
When i see the page with a small screen
[image: small screen view]

this is the structure that I've used:

```
<row>
    <col>2</col>
    <col>
        <row><col>1</col></row>
        <row><col>3</col></row>
    </col>
</row>
```

I could invert the two "main" cols but I cant' insert the block 2 between the others...
Any suggestion?

Sorry for my poor english...

Comment: What have you tried so far? You have not posted any code. <row><col> is not useful "code"

Answer (score 0):

If you can do it in CSS then it can be done using some or all of the classes in Bootstrap 3, but in this instance you need to write your own css to do part of the job. 
Depending on your need you may need to employ jQuery or some other means of getting two equal heights of the 1 & 3 column if your design doesn't work with pixel heights on the min-width. The larger viewport design kicks in at the 768px min width.

Also, the code you provided in your question indicates a lack of reading the documentation for Bootstrap AND understanding how to use CSS and html, there's no such thing as just a `<row>` or just a `<col>`.

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/hodan/1/edit

[image]

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row custom-row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 one">
         <div class="content"> 1 </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 two">
         <div class="content">2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 three">
         <div class="content">3</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
   .one > .content {
        background: lavender
    }
    .two > .content {
        background: lightblue
    }
    .three > .content {
        background: gold
    }
    .one,
    .two,
    .three {
        margin-bottom: 10px
    }
    .content {padding:20px;font-size:50px}

    @media (min-width:768px) { 
        .one,
        .two,
        .three {
            margin-bottom: 0
        }
        .custom-row {
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .one {
            float: right
        }
        .three {
            float: right;
            clear: right;
        }
        .one > .content,
        .three > .content {
            height: 300px;
        }
        .two > .content {
            padding-bottom: 9999px;
            margin-bottom: -9999px;
        }
        .one {
            margin-bottom: 30px
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach using the included `pull-left`, `pull-right` classes..

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 pull-right">
          1
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 pull-left">
          2
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 pull-right">
          3
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/yEcLsEeXLt